# How to download aws s3 bucket objects in flutter?

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-s3

I have a Flutter app and I need to download files, images, or text from an object storage service like AWS S3. I have the key names of all the objects that I want to download, but I am not sure how to download them and save them locally in the system.

Can someone guide me on how to download these objects using their key names and save them locally in the system in Flutter?

Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need url of the file and with that you can download file.

Comment: ok can you suggest me to how to find buckets location/region in flutter?